# how to get value from array of hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

how to get value from array of hash in ruby

example :

```
abc = [{"1"=>"a"}, {"2"=>"b"}, {"3"=>"c"}]
```

how to get result :

```
result = "a"
```

how do that? thanks

Comment: what exactly you want?

Comment: Your sample code may be a little too simplistic. Try to provide a workable use case, so that people trying to answer can distinguish between what will be a useful answer and what will be a trivial case.

Comment: Bad example: Is the value you are looking for always in the first hash in the array, does the hash always have only one key and is the key always `'1'`?

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
result = abc[0]["1"]
# => "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

this will print the values like a b c ....

```
abc.each do |x|
  x.each do |key, value|
    puts value
  end
end
```

Comment: how to get just value 'a'?

Comment: like this? `abc.first['1']`

Answer (score 0):

here is my suggestion:

```
abc = [{"1"=>"a"}, {"2"=>"b"}, {"3"=>"c"}]

collect = abc.collect{|x| x[key] }

result = collect.compact.first
```